# I need help setting up my Cisco SG-200 and SignaMax 065-1100 MM fiber link

Tags: networking, cisco, fiber

I replaced a broken SignaMax switch with built-in fiber connectors with a Cisco SG-200 unit and a GLC-GE-100FX mini-GBIC.  The other end of the run is using a SignaMax 065-1100 media converter and I used a Cables To Go 37945 LC/ST Plenum-Rated Duplex 62.5/125 Multimode Fiber Patch Cable to link them together.

I'm not a fiber specialist but I think everything is hooked up correctly and it should work, but it doesn't.  The Cisco lights up the LINK light but never shows any activity and the SignaMax media converter never seems to LINK.  Is there some setting on the Cisco that I'm missing?  Is there a magically fiber incantation that I have to read?  :/

I like the clean install of the mini-GBIC solution (no external power brick, etc.) but I'm on the verge of just abandoning it and purchasing another media converter.  :(